# How to pronounce "得" in 我的生命因得與萬物漂浮進空間的蔚藍

Tags: pronounciation

我的生命因**得**與萬物漂浮進空間的蔚藍

This is a sentence from a poem by the Indian poet Tagore. I'm asking how is 得 pronounced here (dé or děi)? And what does 因得與 mean? I'm interpreting it as meaning "because I must with", but I don't know if that is correct. Thank you.

Comment: What is that sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: Do you have a rough idea of when the translation was done?

Comment: The translation from Bengali to English, as given by the author, is: *My life is glad to be floating with all things into the blue of space*. See stanza #150 from https://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/rt/stray.htm

Comment: I suggest providing more context from the original work for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence does not make sense, but I guess it meant to say:

- 我的生命"**因而**得[dé]與"萬物... - My life "**thus** be able gether with" all things...

Comment: I am sure it makes perfect sense in Bengali ?

Comment: @WayneCheah Could be. I am waiting for clarification. PdotWang may get it right if 因 represents 因為.

Comment: Agree with r13, the given Chinese is nonsense, even as poetry!

Answer (score 1):

“我的生命因得與萬物漂浮進空間的蔚藍” = “我的生命, 因**得**與萬物(一起漂浮), 漂浮進空間的蔚藍”. "得" is pronounced (dé) "得到(这样的机会)", and it means "to be able to",  "to be proud of being able to".

“我的生命因得與萬物漂浮進空間的蔚藍”, or "我的生命因得与万物漂浮进空间的蔚蓝" is from a poem of Rabindranath Tagore. [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1512080777182381660.html). The following is a version of its Chinese translation.

"我的思想闪耀於绿叶的扶疏；我的心灵歌唱於阳光的抚触；**我的生命因得与万物一起飘浮，而走进蔚蓝的空间**，游离并欣喜於时间的黑暗里。"

"我的生命因**得**与万物一起飘浮，而走进蔚蓝的空间" "Wǒ de shēngmìng yīn **dé** yǔ wànwù yīqǐ piāofú, ér zǒu jìn wèilán de kōngjiān". - Because it **can** float with all things together, my life enters the blue space.

But I think "空间的蔚蓝" is better. It follows the form of "绿叶的扶疏", "阳光的抚触", and "时间的黑暗". I do not see the poem in its original language.

Answer (score 0):

Not happy with the translation, I made my own interpretation and obviated 得.

Not happy with "my life is glad" How could a *life* be *glad*, a human emotion? Poetic license?

My thoughts shimmer with these shimmering leaves
我的思绪伴随着闪闪发光的树叶跳动着,
and my heart sings with the touch of this sunlight;
我的心脏伴随着阳光的抚摸歌唱着；
my life is glad to be floating with all things into the blue of space,
我的生命愉快地与时间万物一起漂浮在这蓝色空间里,
into the dark of time.
漂浮在这时间的黑洞里.